# How to add config to ${HOME}/.kube/config?

Tags: kubernetes

I have new Civo cluster,I downloaded config

```
 kubectl config --kubeconfig=civo-enroute-demo-kubeconfig
```

does not work

```
Modify kubeconfig files using subcommands like "kubectl config set current-context my-context"

 The loading order follows these rules:

  1.  If the --kubeconfig flag is set, then only that file is loaded. The flag may only be set once and no merging takes
place.
  2.  If $KUBECONFIG environment variable is set, then it is used as a list of paths (normal path delimiting rules for
your system). These paths are merged. When a value is modified, it is modified in the file that defines the stanza. When
a value is created, it is created in the first file that exists. If no files in the chain exist, then it creates the
last file in the list.
  3.  Otherwise, ${HOME}/.kube/config is used and no merging takes place.
```

Output config view

```
kubectl config view --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://00.220.23.220:6443
  name: enroute-demo
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: enroute-demo
    user: enroute-demo
  name: enroute-demo
current-context: enroute-demo
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: enroute-demo
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

How should the kubectl command look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a kubeconfig file with kubectl as

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=config_file.yaml command
```

Example:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=civo-enroute-demo-kubeconfig.yaml get nodes
```

OR
You can export `KUBECONFIG` and use `kubectl` command

Comment: civo-enroute-demo-kubeconfig is not with yaml extension.

Comment: The extension should not matter if the file itself is yaml formatted